# Forward template deduction from constructor through type-alias

Tags: c++, syntax, sfinae

This question about the syntax of C++ and how do do something specific.

I have an `Employee` class with 2 member functions that are arrays. One array stores all the free time the `Employee` has and the other stores the shifts the `Employee` is covering. I would like to define a helper class that lets me use a for range loop (`for (:)`) over either of the arrays. For example if I do this:

```
for (auto& ts : employee_freetime_iterator{ employee })
```

It will iterate over the free time the employee has. And if I do this:

```
for (auto& ts : employee_shift_iterator{ employee })
```

It will iterate over the shifts. I have a class that is defined like this:

```
template <typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Employee, std::remove_cv_t<T>>>
>
struct employee_shift_iterator { 
    employee_shift_iterator(T& e);
};
```

In the declaration, `T` is either going to be a `Employee` or an `const Employee` and the 3rd template parameter is a SFINAE to force this fact. Now If I use this class then I will have to copy and paste it twice, one for `employee_freetime_iterator` and one for `employee_shift_iterator`. To reduce the code redundancy, I choose to do this:

```
enum ScheduleType {
    FREE,
    SHIFT,
    ST_TOTAL
};

template <typename T, ScheduleType ST,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Employee, std::remove_cv_t<T>>>
>
struct employee_iterator {
    constexpr static ScheduleType mScheduleType = ST;

    employee_iterator(T& e);
};
```

Now I can use the `ScheduleType` to choose different helper functions that let me iterate over the `Employee` class. The thing that I am trying to do is to create 2 different type alias' (one for each `ScheduleType`) like this:

```
template <typename T>
using employee_freetime_iterator = employee_iterator<T, FREE>;

template <typename T, typename SFINAE>
using employee_shift_iterator = employee_iterator<T, SHIFT>;
```

But how can I forward the constructor parameter so that the `T` template param will be automatically inferred? Just compiling as is gives me this error:

```
src/main.cpp:47:40: error: missing template arguments before ‘{’ token
  auto test = employee_freetime_iterator{ em };
```

Where em is an employee I created earlier in my code. I have refactored the code and removed the unnecessary parts of it and pasted it below.

```
enum ScheduleType {
    FREE,
    SHIFT,
    ST_TOTAL
};

// Forward declaration
template <typename T, ScheduleType ST, typename SFINAE>
class employee_iterator;

struct Employee {
    std::vector<TimeSlot> mFreeTime;
    std::vector<TimeSlot> mShifts;

    using timeslot_iterator       = typename std::vector<TimeSlot>::iterator;
    using timeslot_const_iterator = typename std::vector<TimeSlot>::const_iterator;

    timeslot_const_iterator begin(const std::vector<TimeSlot>& s) const;
    timeslot_const_iterator end(const std::vector<TimeSlot>& s) const;

    timeslot_iterator begin(std::vector<TimeSlot>& s);
    timeslot_iterator end(std::vector<TimeSlot>& s);

};

// Helper class
template <typename T, ScheduleType ST,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Employee, std::remove_cv_t<T>>>
>
struct employee_iterator {
    using iterator = std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<T>, Employee::timeslot_const_iterator, Employee::timeslot_iterator>;

    constexpr static ScheduleType mScheduleType = ST;

    std::add_pointer_t<T> mEmployee;

    employee_iterator() = delete;
    employee_iterator(T& e);    
    employee_iterator(T* e);
};

// Helper class c'tors
template <typename T, ScheduleType ST, typename SFINAE>
employee_iterator<T, ST, SFINAE>::employee_iterator(T& e) 
    : mEmployee{ &e }
    {  }

template <typename T, ScheduleType ST, typename SFINAE>
employee_iterator<T, ST, SFINAE>::employee_iterator(T* e)
    : mEmployee{ e }
    {  }

// begin and end functions for iteration over Employee
template <typename T, ScheduleType ST, typename SFINAE>
typename employee_iterator<T, ST, SFINAE>::iterator begin(employee_iterator<T, ST, SFINAE> it) {
    if constexpr (ST == FREE)
        return it.mEmployee->begin(it.mEmployee->mFreeTime);
    else
        return it.mEmployee->begin(it.mEmployee->mShifts);
}

template <typename T, ScheduleType ST, typename SFINAE>
typename employee_iterator<T, ST, SFINAE>::iterator end(employee_iterator<T, ST, SFINAE> it) {
    if constexpr (ST == FREE)
        return it.mEmployee->end(it.mEmployee->mFreeTime);
    else
        return it.mEmployee->end(it.mEmployee->mShifts);
}

/// Type alias
template <typename T>
using employee_freetime_iterator = employee_iterator<T, FREE>;

template <typename T>
using employee_shift_iterator = employee_iterator<T, SHIFT>;
```

EDIT: I know my code I wrote is long and confusing, so I created something really short that shows my issue. How can I get this to work?

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
using my_pair = std::pair<T1, T2>;


int main() {
    // I can do this:
    // will be inferred as std::pair<double, int>
    std::pair test1{ 1.0, 5 };

    // However the compiler has issues with this:
    my_pair test2{1.0, 3};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need template argument deduction you need to introduce functions:

```
namespace detail{
  // ... employee_iterator, ScheduleType etc, ...
  template <typename T>
  using employee_freetime_iterator = employee_iterator<T, FREE>;

  template <typename T>
  using employee_shift_iterator = employee_iterator<T, SHIFT>;
}

template<class T>
detail::employee_freetime_iterator<T> employee_freetime_iterator(T& e) {
  return {e};
}

template<class T>
detail::employee_shift_iterator<T> employee_shift_iterator(T& e) {
  return {e};
}
```

Unfortunately class template argument deduction is not allowed for template type aliases. You will have to go with a function template if you want to forgo explicit template arguments.

Comment: I thought about that, but I was wondering if there was a way to go about it without functions. Because it's just template type aliasing, there may be a way to do it that I haven't seen

Comment: @Aryan Class template argument deduction is not allowed for template type aliases. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008092/class-template-argument-deduction-not-working-with-alias-template

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the link.