# Missing deduction guide for alias template in C++20?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, template-argument-deduction

Since C++20, we have deduction guides (CTAD) for alias templates. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41008415) post explains the concept pretty well.
My question is: Why does the deduction fail for `FooAlias` in the following piece of code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TPeM9h6on))?

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(T) {}
};

template <class T>
struct Selector {
    using type = T;
};

template <class T>
using FooAlias = Foo<typename Selector<T>::type>;

void test(){
    Foo f1{3.0}; // Compiles
    FooAlias f2{3.0}; // Error, class template argument deduction failed
}
```

The line with `f2` fails to compile on both MSVC19.30 and gcc11 (clang13 does not yet support deduction for alias templates).

My guess is that `typename Selector<T>::type` in the definition of `FooAlias` is not a ["simple-template-id"](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:simple-template-id). But I failed to comprehend the standard here. Specifically, if I try to follow the standard, a ["simple-template-id"](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:simple-template-id) can contain multiple ["template-arguments"](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:template-argument), where each of them can be an ["id-expression"](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.general#nt:id-expression), which can be a ["qualified-id"](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:qualified-id), which can be of the form ["simple-template-id::unqualified-id"](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:qualified-id). And to me, `Selector<T>::type` looks to satisfy this. What am I missing?

Comment: This is non-deduced context and it has nothing to do with alias templates or deduction guides. Any old function template like `template <class T> void foo(typename Bar<T>::type)` will not deduce `T`.

Comment: Hu, obviously I was thinking way too complex. Thanks!